# Entity Framework Core DbContextFactory not registering

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphql, entity-framework-core

I'm using .NET 5 and Entity Framework Core, along with Hot Chocolate to create a GraphQL api. One of the things listed as being a necessary change to get proper performance out of the api is the use of parallel actions being run on the same context, which EF is not good at. The stated fix is to use a "pooled context factory".

The problem comes when I try to build the context model and database on initial startup. My context factory is not registering, but a standard dbContext is. I'm not sure what I'm missing or where to look for the problem/solution, so I'm appealing to a wider audience here in the hope that someone else can see what I can't.

Here is the ConfigureServices part of Startup where I am adding the context factory:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Configure context
    services.AddDbContextFactory<AppContext>((s, options) =>
        options
            .UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("TransactDB"))
            .UseLoggerFactory(s.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>())
    );

    // This bit works if I use it, but the bit above doesn't.
    //services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => 
    //  options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("TransactDB"))
    //);

    // other code removed for brevity

}
```

Here is the code for the Program file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        CreateDbIfNotExists(host);
        host.Run();
    }

    private static void CreateDbIfNotExists(IHost host)
    {
        using (IServiceScope scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            IServiceProvider services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                AppContext context = services.GetRequiredService<AppContext>(); // this line here is where it breaks
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ILogger<Program> logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured while creating the DB.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(c => c.AddConsole())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Here is my context:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext(DbContextOptions<AppContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        // intentionally left blank
    }

    public DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        new SiteEntityTypeConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Site>());
        new CustomerEntityTypeConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>());
        new EmployeeEntityTypeConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>());
        new VehicleEntityTypeConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>());
        new TransactionEntityTypeConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>());

        foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the error I am seeing in my console when I start the application:

```
fail: AppApi.Program[0]
    An error occured while creating the DB.
    System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'AppApi.Common.Data.AppContext' has been registered.
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
       at AppApi.Program.CreateDbIfNotExists(IHost host) in C:\Users\me\dev\App\back-end\AppApi\Program.cs:line 26
```

The error above does not get logged if I use the standard `AddDbContext<AppContext>`, even when using both. This implies, to me, that the `AddDbContextFactory<AppContext>` isn't actually doing anything at all, but VisualStudio recognizes it as a valid method on the IServiceCollection interface, so I'm not sure why it isn't registering. I'm sure it's something small and I will probably have some choice words when I finally find it, but for now I'm at a loss.

Let me know if there are other bits of code or other information people need to look at. I'm going to keep picking at it myself and will provide an answer if I find one before someone else.

Comment: See EF Core docs - [Using a DbContext factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)

Comment: @IvanStoev unless I have gone blind, my implementation follows the EF Core docs. If you can spot the piece I'm missing, please let me know because I certainly can't.

Comment: `services.GetRequiredService<AppContext>()` does not work with reqistered factory - as you can see in the link, the factory is used differently, e.g. obtain a factory `var factory = services.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<AppContext>>();`, then use it to obtain context(s) `using (var context = factory.CreateDbContext())`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@IvanStoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) for pointing me in the right direction. I was under the impression that creating an instance of the context from the factory was only needed in the controllers and services.

The working code looks like this:

```
...
private static void CreateDbIfNotExists(IHost host)
{
    using (IServiceScope scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        IServiceProvider services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var factory = services.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<BennyNetContext>>();
            using (BennyNetContext context = factory.CreateDbContext())
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ILogger<Program> logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured while creating the DB.");
        }
    }
}
...
```